# Reading JSON from server JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to read a JSON file hosted on a server.

The link is http://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/info/index.json

When you go to that link, it will download info.json. I need to fetch this json file and read is using jquery.getJSON.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, go ahead! Or did you want help with some code? If so, let's see what you tried!

Comment: [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Where is a question mark in your question?

Comment: People... "How do I use jquery.getJSON to access an external link"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this client side assuming your you page is not on the domain noaa.gov, and the server doesn't support JSONP.  With JSONP, you would add a parameter "callback" and provide the name of the function to call with the data.  (which is no longer JSON, it is the actual objects/arrays, so no need to call)

Basically, your issue is with the "same origin policy", you can't do XMLHttpRequest cross domain unless the server is cooperating, either via JSONP (which is really a bit of a hack and  dangerous if you don't trust the server), or more modern approaches (http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html )

Answer (score 0):

Download the .json using a server-side http mechanism like cURL (php) and serve it to the client from your own server.